# Code-completing/auto-completing ArcPy scripts using Notepad++ (external editor)?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, notepad++

I have been scripting in Python for ArcGIS 10, and so far I have just been using Notepad++.

I like how the Python command line interface code-completes arcpy functionality for you, showing you your options, and I was wondering if there is a way to add this feature to an external editor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I recommend [WingWare IDE](http://www.wingware.com/). It seems to have the best debugging and code completion out of the Python IDEs I've seen. One of the motivating factors for arcpy in 10.0 was that it would have better code completion than arcgisscripting offered.

Answer (score 15):

[PyScripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) is my choice. It's free and open source and a lightweight and quick install. There is even a registry-free installation that doesn't require admin rights for installation.

Comment: Code completion seems to work for the Arc10 arcpy module, but I was not able to enable it for Arc 9.x.  For future readers, to enable arcpy (Arc10) code-completion in PyScripter, go to Tools--> Options--> IDE Options--> and add "arcpy" to the "special packages" line of Code Completion section.  NOTE: code-completion is case sensitive, so arcpy.copyfeatures will not code-complete, but arcpy.CopyFeatures will code-complete (note the capital "C" and "F".

Comment: An additional note on code completion... you can disable case sensitivity by unchecking "case sensitive" in the same location as noted above.

Comment: Also, the `Ctrl-Shift-Space` hotkey will bring up the code completion "call tip" if you are for example in the middle of writing a function parameter list and you did something to close it.

Comment: The question is about autocompletion of ArcPy but your "answer" makes no mention of it.  Please address this ASAP, because it is currently at risk of being deleted.

Answer (score 8):

MS recently released [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) - once you follow a few steps outlined here: http://blog.guerrillagis.net/?p=878 Visual Studio will provide you with intellisense, method signatures, syntax highlighting, a REPL and a debugger.

Comment: +1! Visual Studio 2010 with PyTools is a fantastic Python IDE. It even integrates with the Visual Studio Integrated Shell for a completely free setup even without any existing Microsoft licenses.

Comment: I use Python Tools for Visual Studio too - moved here from PythonWin several years ago and have never gone back

Answer (score 7):

I'd try [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) using the [Pydev](http://pydev.org/) extensions. I know it didn't do code completion very well with the python geoprocessor in 9.3, and I haven't got 10 to play around with yet, but even without it, it is a much nicer editor with some very cool features.

Comment: Have finally got down to playing with 10 - code complete does work w. Eclipse. Good luck to anyone else trying it out!

Answer (score 5):

Code completion is a feature of the editor, [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/698/is-there-an-ide-that-provides-code-completion-for-python) has a listing of editors which support code completion. In Notepad++, you can enable autocompletion [as a preference](http://cybernetnews.com/notepad-50-can-auto-complete-code/).

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful. I have autocompletion enabled, but it is only completing core python code. Is it possible to have it autocomplete arcpy functions? Thanks for the help, I am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be poorly known that IDLE supports autocompletion reliably too.

If you are using it with ArcPy always run the `import arcpy` part of the script once so that your script window becomes aware of that site-package.

However, if you do not see autocompletion kick in then the trick is to use "Ctrl + Spacebar" to trigger it.

I have seen this mentioned here at [Getting ArcPy autocomplete to work in IDLE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76331/how-do-i-get-arcpy-mapping-autocomplete-to-work-in-idle-in-a-new-window) and on StackOverflow at [Python IDLE. Auto-complete/Show completions not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089476/python-idle-auto-complete-show-completions-not-working) but it is no doubt in the IDLE documentation somewhere too.

Answer (score 1):

[Active State komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide) works fine for me. I just added a reference to the arcpy directory in the preferences. It has good debugging and a good interface. Autocompletion works for arcpy and my own libraries.

Comment: Hi Neil, can you better describe how? Im trying to add it on preferences as described but not having luck finding the .xml for code intelli inside arcpy folder.