# Getting ArcPy autocomplete to work in IDLE?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, idle

I want to write scripts in IDLE, but I love how the built in python window in ArcGIS 10.2 automatically fills in the module names as you start typing them.

For example, if I type `arcpy.Lis...`, the python window in ArcGIS will suggest `arcpy.ListDataStoreItems`.

In IDLE, that doesn't occur, and I feel that if I type one wrong letter or mess up a case, it will cause the script to crash and burn.

At the top of my script, I write:

```
import arcpy.mapping as mapping
# etc
```

However I don't believe this runs until the script runs, so how can the window know what I've imported. Can I do something in the shell so that the autocomplete works in IDLE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you've imported arcpy you can go to the IDLE menu bar and click Edit>Show Completions. This will activate autocomplete for arcpy scripts. This can also be activated with the keyboard shortcut CTL + space. Once you type an open parenthesis IDLE will display the syntax for the arcpy class, just like in the python window in ArcGIS.

---

If the above does not work, an extra step may be needed, which is that until you have run the `import arcpy` line within IDLE once it will not have access to the arcpy site-package to enable auto-completion of ArcPy code.