# Autocomplete not working for ArcPy in PyCharm

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, pycharm

I'm trying to set up auto complete for ArcPy in PyCharm, but while submodules seem to have auto complete suggestions, the ArcPy module itself doesn't have completions provided.

Example of unsuccessful auto complete:

[image: Ex. 1 Unsuccessful]

But when typing `arcpy.gp.` I see suggestions, as expected.

I thought that the submodules and functions/classes directly available from `arcpy` would be shown or help for specific functions would display.

I followed the instructions for [setting up PyCharm to reference ArcPy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/how-to-setup-pycharm-to-reference-arcpy). I ensured that the project interpreter was configured correctly, and also my `PYTHONPATH` in the application. I have also tried invalidating the cache and restarting PyCharm but did not see any improvement.

Is this auto complete supposed to work, and if so, how do I configure PyCharm to do it?

I am using PyCharm Community Edition 2016.2.3 and Arcpy as included with ArcGIS Desktop 10.3.

Comment: I'm using pychrm and it's working for me. Do you install another version of python other than the default python?

Comment: What's your version of pycharm? When you install pycharm it's automatically index whole packages. It takes some minutes to import all of packages. Did you see indexing process ?

Comment: On my machines, pycharm is a bit laggy with auto-completion on `arcpy`. If you wait a few seconds, does that help?

Comment: You're right. I tried again, and it just takes awhile to show up. Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: what I have noticed is that its not working until the first run. Simply start your script with Import arcpy and run it... then you will have Autocomplete functionality enabled. Looks like, pycharm needs to load arcpy library first, I think.

Comment: @ChrisL Your comment makes sense, I see the [same thing with IDLE](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/94754/115), so I think you should copy/paste your comment into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

what I have noticed is that its not working until the first run. Simply start your script with `Import arcpy` and run it... then you will have Autocomplete functionality enabled. Looks like, pycharm needs to load arcpy library first,